# Salvar imagem WebBrowser Delphi

Tags: html, delphi

Recebo uma imagem de uma camera IP e exibo em um TWebBrowser gostaria de salvar essa imagem em uma pasta.
O codigo fonte do HTML gerado é esse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://192.168.25.3/admin/cgi-bin/get_frame.pl">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: o que acontece se você executar esse caminho ai do `src` em um navegador comum?

Comment: Aparece a imagem que preciso centralizada

Comment: Ou seja, você não tem acesso à imagem, tem acesso à pagina onde ela esta! Pelo WebBrowser vai ser complicado!

Comment: Pois é... pensei em alguma rotina pra capturar a tag IMG mas se ela tivesse um ID ficaria melhor.